# Is the proverb "it's not over until the fat lady sings" offensive?

Tags: proverbs

The proverb **"it's not/it ain't over until the fat lady sings"** is generally understood to be referencing the stereotypically overweight sopranos of the opera (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_ain%27t_over_till_the_fat_lady_sings)). I've got a feeling that the proverb is offensive to female opera singers because it seems to stress that they weigh too much. That's why I'd prefer "it's not over till it's over" to "it's not over until the fat lady sings."

But I may be wrong, and there is nothing wrong about the saying in question...

I wonder if the proverb is really not so neutral. Isn't "fat lady" disapproving, making the whole sentence sound, well, slightly offensive?

Comment: Why is this being voted to close? If you don't know, you don't know.

Comment: @Mitch - The question boils down to "Is it offensive to stereotype opera singers as fat?" and "Is calling people fat offensive?". Which doesn't seem to be a good fit for this site to me.

Comment: @AndyT It's sociolinguistics which is on-topic. Any part of the meaning/connotation of a word is fair game, like extent of tabooness/offensiveness/vulgarity. The question is not about 'should', but about the effect on the hearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are many sites that wonder about this in the same way](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=%22fat+lady+sings%22+%22offensive%22), and news articles about 'PC run amok', and brouhaha over hypersensitivity:

> [‘It’s not over till the fat lady sings’: ABC says popular saying isn’t PC](https://startsat60.com/news/its-not-over-till-the-fat-lady-sings-abc-pc-debate) (Australian, 27 Jul 2018)
>
> ["It ain't over until the Fat Lady sings!"
>   There are suggestions this saying is offensive and fat-shaming!](https://twitter.com/thetodayshow/status/1022276304631083009?lang=en) (US, 25 Jul 2018)
>
> [Show really is over after the 'fat lady' quits](https://www.express.co.uk/news/world/150620/Show-really-is-over-after-the-fat-lady-quits) (UK, 9 Jan 2010)

What this tells me is that there are some people who find 'fat lady' offensive (it's hard to tell how many, but certainly the literal opera singers, the object of the quip), and there are also some people who are upset that some other people find it offensive.

I gather from this that it is slightly offensive. Whether it *should* be considered offensive or not is a value judgement that is a bit argumentative. But if you use the phrase just be aware that even euphemisms ('portly', 'hefty', 'husky') might imply offensiveness.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps it is currently perceived as offensive by heavy female opera singers but as a slim male, with a mediocre voice at best, I cannot speak regarding their attitudes toward this idiom. I can, however, speak regarding the population as whole.

The origin of this phrase is:

> 'The phrase is generally understood to be referencing the stereotypically overweight sopranos of the opera. The imagery of Richard Wagner's opera cycle Der Ring des Nibelungen and its last part, Götterdämmerung, is typically the one used in depictions accompanying reference to the phrase. The "fat lady" is the valkyrie Brünnhilde, who is traditionally presented as a very buxom lady with horned helmet, spear and round shield (although Amalie Materna played Brünnhilde during Wagner's lifetime (1876) with a winged helmet). Her farewell scene lasts almost twenty minutes and leads directly to the finale of the whole Ring Cycle.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_ain%27t_over_till_the_fat_lady_sings#cite_note-2) As Götterdämmerung is about the end of the world (or at least the world of the Norse gods), in a very significant way "it is [all] over when the fat lady sings."

[wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It_ain%27t_over_till_the_fat_lady_sings#cite_note-2)

In that era obesity was celebrated and not looked down upon as it is currently. A most recent example is Lillian Russell, a famous heavy actress and singer, who was regarded as beautiful even in the early 20th century!

[blog.sermo.com](http://blog.sermo.com/2015/07/02/history-obesity-renaissance-1910/)

Nowadays, most people don't even think of the origin when they use the idiom. They simply interpret it as 'don't count your chickens before they hatch,' or as you suggested, 'It's not over till it's over.'

Therefore I would suggest that most people would not find the idiom, or a sentence containing it, offensive.

Comment: Your conclusion seems at odds with the direction of your answer. At the beginning you say that someone who was heavy at the beginning of the 20th c was still regarded as. Eautiful, implying that that was changing, and later in the 20th c it would not be as beautiful. And I presume that not beautiful is going in the direction of not complimentary and therefore more offensive than not.

Comment: The introductory paragraph was listing a possible exception to the rule. The middle paragraphs were explaining why its source is not offensive, and why, in general, the majority of people would not find it offensive. The conclusion summarized the body and introduction.